How to access Translation object t within Shopify theme app extension's liquid snippet ? [handlebar.js]
This is my .liquid file
offers.liquid file
{% raw %}

<script id="cross-sell-popup" type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-no-instant>
<div>
    <div class="default-message">{{{notifications_message}}}
    </div>
    <div class="message"> Get all these items for special bundle offer price!</div>
    <div>{{ 'section.bundle.bundle_static_title' | t}}</div>
</div>
</script>

...

{% endraw %}

This is the en.default.json inside locales
{
  "section": {
    "bundle": {
      "bundle_static_title": "Enter store using password:"
    }
  }
}

This is the error I'm getting when I run the app:

Error compiling HTML Error: Parse error on line 10:
...undle_static_title' | t}}</div>  <div cl
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'CLOSE_BLOCK_PARAMS'

image
Language: JQuery + handlebar.js
When User changes the language from the online storefront, I would like my Shopify app to translate text.
For this, I have added locales/en.json , locales/fr.json files for now.
I'm trying to access it's contents using the 'path-from-json' | t as suggested in documentation, it's giving a parsing error on the pipe.
